# Width of content not filling mobile screen

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make my design mobile friendly. What I have is that everything fits nicely when I look at the design on http://ipadpeek.com/ (Great Tool!) although when I actually view it through my iPhone 4 the content only takes up around 80% of the page, whereas the remaining 20% is a white background.

There is only one element which appears to fit the whole width and this has the following style:

```
<div class="text-elements">
<h2>Your website can achieve...</h2>
</div>

.text-elements {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 75px 10px;

    h2 {
      font-size: 4em;
      width: 100%;
    } 
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI most of the online iPad style tools such as http://ipadpeek.com/ don't tend to pick up any of these overflow issues anyways.

In the end I found that the issue was at least one or more divs which had explicit widths set, but which were quite hard to find as culprits!

**Tips for anyone else with this problem:**

1. If you know any design will be responsive, use `max-width: Xpx`, `width: 100%`, in your main stylesheets on any explicit width divs to avoid them becoming a culprit in later course.
2. When using width: 100% on items, make sure you add any additional padding to the inner div (especially if it is in pixels), or account for it such as `width: 95%`, `padding: 2.5%`.
3. Try `overflow: hidden` on some of the main wrappers which hold your content to see where issues are coming from.